# How to prove that $\frac{1}{n+1} = {\sqrt{n\over n+1}}\implies n = \Phi$?

Tags: arithmetic, golden-ratio

Consider:

$$\frac{1}{n+1} = {\sqrt{n\over n+1}}$$

How could one prove that $n$ is of such form that:

$$\frac{1}{n+1} = {\sqrt{n\over n+1}}\implies n = {\sqrt{5\,}-1 \over 2} \implies n = \Phi$$

where $\Phi$ denotes the golden ratio?

**Edit:**

I noticed that:

$$\frac{1}{n+1} = {\sqrt{n\over n+1}} \implies \left ( \frac{1}{n+1}\right ) ^2 = \left ({\sqrt{n\over n+1}}\right)^2\implies$$
$${1\over(n+1)^2} =  {n\over(n+1)}\implies n = {1\over n+1} \implies$$
$${1\over{1+{1\over1+n}}} \approx \Phi$$

as $$\Phi = {1\over{1+{1\over{1+{1\over\dots}}}}}$$

which should be proof enough.

Comment: have you tried squaring both sides?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

Just square both sides to get $$\frac1{(n+1)^2}=\frac n{n+1}\implies n^2+n-1=0$$ assuming $n+1\ne0$

---

Alternatively, $\sqrt{n+1}=(n+1)\sqrt n\implies 1=\sqrt{n(n+1)}$ assuming $n+1\ne0$

Now, square both sides to get $n^2+n=1$

So, $n=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt5}2$

As $\sqrt{\frac n{n+1}}$ is considered to be $\ge 0,\frac1{n+1}\ge 0\implies n\ge -1$

Now, as $-\frac{1+\sqrt5}2<-1,$ it is an [extraneous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions) root

Comment: I figure its briefly worth mentioning that squaring can introduce "extra" solutions to the problem - so you'll have to rule out one of the solutions to the quadratic as being an answer by substituting it back into the original expression.

Comment: @AndrewD, did you mean this?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.